# Add Page Tags Programatically in DotNetNuke

Tags: tags, dotnetnuke, taxonomy

I am creating a new tab in dotnetnuke but I also want to add tags for my tab (pages). I don't know I how to accomplish this task. I have use taxonomy class but in that class we can define tags but I want to add tags programatically for my page when I am adding a new page (tab).

Answer (score 3):

Try using a `DotNetNuke.Entities.Content.ContentController` to get a `ContentItem` instance based on the tab's `ContentItemId`.  You can then add to the `Terms` list and use the `ContentController` to update the content item.